# Pause resume function for mediarecorder android Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I would like to record a audio file and allow to pause and resume recording.

I have done some research and looks like media recorder api does not have pause function. So one workaround I found was to save a file in temporary location on pause and on resume merge two files and save on the actual location.

I did not find any related code for this. It would be helpful if anybody can provide me with some reference or some step which I should follow.

I also found out that there is mp4parser which is used to merge two files but since I am using xamarin I do not hav that option.

**Edit**

```
public async Task record()
{
    try
    {
        string path = getTemporaryFileName();
        recorder.SetAudioSource(AudioSource.Mic);
        recorder.SetOutputFormat(OutputFormat.Mpeg4);
        recorder.SetAudioEncoder(AudioEncoder.Aac);
        recorder.SetAudioSamplingRate(44100);
        recorder.SetAudioEncodingBitRate(8000);
        recorder.SetOutputFile(path);
        recorder.Prepare();
        recorder.Start();


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string s = ex.Message;
        throw ex;
    }
}

public async Task stopRecording()
{
    try
    {
        recorder.Stop();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string s = ex.Message;
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

On play button click I am calling record() function and on stop I call stop(). I want to be able to pause and resume.

Comment: Can you show your code

Comment: Try this link it might be helpful for you.  https://github.com/lassana/continuous-audiorecorder

Comment: @NiteshKumar thanks for quick response. I have modified my question.

Comment: Would this work for xamarin?